# How can I view .ctg files taken from my Canon camera?

Tags: canon, jpeg, file-format

How can I see the images taken from my Canon camera. All files are converted into CTG, and I could not open either in the camera nor on the PC.

Comment: What size are most of these .ctg files?

Comment: What camera model do you have? Is there any setting allowing you to choose what file type camera should save (raw vs jpg) ?

Answer (score 6):

.ctg files are only for use by the camera as Catalog index files and are used when managing and displaying photos in the camera.

There is no reason to try to view them as there should be .jpg or .CR2 (RAW) files to view on your PC.

Comment: But what if there are no .jpg or CR2 files to view but only .ctg (and those only temporarily). Why is my camera suddenly doing this and how do I go back to taking RAW/j.peg? (I have not changed the settings - still set as shooting in RAW).

Comment: @HelleMøller This is another question that you should ask (or look for, should it already have ben asked before).